# MIME types not recognized by media library

Tags: uploads, media-library

We have several thousand MP3 files that were transferred to WP (from a dying Drupal site) via a custom script by the developer, with whom we don't have contact anymore. Wordpress, however, doesn't recognize those files' mime type:

[image: A screenshot of the Media Library overlay showing an empty field for the file type]

The server (debian lamp stack) shows that the file has the correct mime time associated with it:

```
# file --mime-type 1-14_FNC.mp3
1-14_FNC.mp3: audio/mpeg
```

Is there a plugin or script that can go through these old files and assign the correct type within Wordpress? (needed to offload them onto s3 with another plugin, heh. That script fails with an empty mime type.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update the mime types via MySQL -- here's the update query I used:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_mime_type` = 'audio/mpeg' WHERE `post_name` LIKE '%mp3%' AND `post_mime_type` != 'audio/mpeg'
```

Setting this also made the correct metadata for the files appear, and the offload plugin worked as expected.

HURRAY